# Create a drop down listBox on Windows Phone 8.1?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, windows, dropdownbox

I am new to app development so just meant to say that I don't have a lot of experience with C# either. So please be simple.

I need to create a drop down list with a textBox. Like when one enters a letter, the drop down list would show the most likely words available in the list.
And the list should keep updating every time a letter is typed.

Comment: You can have a look at this question: [Controls show through ComboBox dropdown on Windows Phone 8.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24577123/controls-show-through-combobox-dropdown-on-windows-phone-8-1)

Answer (score 1):

i would advice you not to go with a dropdown list with a textbox. this is a desktop kind of control. for mobile users its not user friendly to use this kind of control.

because when you type the keyboard shows up hiding 60% of your screen. then you have to press back to hide the keyboard after you type 1 letter. then look at the results and add 1 more letter.. lots of user interactions that wont make your users happy.

Windows phone normally uses a long list selector for cases like this:

example:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj244365(v=vs.105).aspx

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. as a first step, create page with textbox and listbox.
2. Create ViewModel class and set it to DataContext property of your listbox.
3. DataBinding TextBox.Text to  e.g string SearchTerm property of your viewmodel. DataBind ListBox.ItemsSource property to list of your contacts in your viewmodel.

when this is working, let's start with filtering. We will use CollectionView to realtime filtering.

1. CollectionView can filter your contact collection based on predicate. We will create new Collection view, define its filter based on SearchTerm property.
2. DataBindid listbox.ItemsSource to CollectionView instear of original Contacts
3. In SearchTerm property setter we need to call Refresh on CollectionView, so the framework knows that he need to rebind our listbox.

The final xaml:

```
<DockPanel>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding SearchTerm, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
             DockPanel.Dock="Top"/>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding FilteredContacts}" />
</DockPanel>
```

C#:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _searchTerm;

    public ViewModel()
    {
        Contacts = new ObservableCollection<string>
        {
            "Peter", "Daniel", "Kate", "John", "Anthony", "Laura", "Charles"
        };
        FilteredContacts = new ListCollectionView(Contacts);
        FilteredContacts.Filter = contact => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(SearchTerm) || ((string)contact).Contains(SearchTerm);
    }

    public string SearchTerm
    {
        get { return _searchTerm; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _searchTerm) return;
            _searchTerm = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SearchTerm");
            FilteredContacts.Refresh();
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> Contacts { get; private set; }
    public CollectionView FilteredContacts { get; private set; }
}
```

Comment: So what is a ViewModel and how do I create one?
Is it just another class that I should create or some predefined thing?

Comment: It is not predefined class. ViewModel is basically any class, that you assing to DataContext of your Page or UserControl. It should implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695(v=vs.110).aspx

ViewModel class keeps data and behaviour, that you databind to in your pages.

Typically your have one view model class per page. E.g Page1ViewModel, Page2ViewModel etc.

Answer (score -1):

In Windows Phone 8.1, dropdown functionality is achieved with ComboBoxes. This tutorial here should help you: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/2d2d83/combobox-in-windows-phone-8-1/

**Note:** I'm assuming you are creating Windows Phone 8.1 applications based on WinRT runtime. The older Silverlight runtime does not have any support for a dropdown. (Although you can use [Windows Phone toolkit](https://phone.codeplex.com/) to achieve the same)

Comment: This does not solve his most basic requirement - search as you type, or realtime filtering